# Am I using NSE and rlang correctly/reasonably?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, nse, rlang

I've been reading through [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) and trying to apply the ideas it describes in my work.  I have something that works, but it's unclear to me whether I've done it in the "right" way.  Is there something more elegant or concise I could be doing?

I have a `tibble` where rows are scenarios and columns relate to tests that were run in that scenario.  There are two types of columns, those that store a test statistic that was computed in that scenario and those that store the degrees of freedom of that test.

So, here's a small, toy example of the type of data I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(27599)

my_tbl <- data_frame(test1_stat = rnorm(12), test1_df = rep(x = c(1, 2, 3), times = 4), 
                     test2_stat = rnorm(12), test2_df = rep(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), times = 3))
```

I want to compute a summary of each test that will be based on both its `stat` and its `df`.  My example here is that I want to compute the median `stat` for each group, where groups are defined by `df`.  The groupings are not guaranteed to be the same across tests, nor are the number of groups even guaranteed to be the same.

So, here's what I've done:

```
get_test_median = function(df, test_name) {

  stat_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_stat')
  df_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_df')
  median_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_median')

  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(rlang::UQ(rlang::sym(df_col_name))) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(rlang::UQ(median_col_name) := median(x = rlang::UQ(rlang::sym(stat_col_name)), na.rm = TRUE))
}

my_tbl %>% get_test_median(test_name = 'test1')
my_tbl %>% get_test_median(test_name = 'test2')
```

This works.  But is it how an experienced `rlang` user would do it?  I am new to NSE, and a bit surprised to be using two nested `rlang` functions repeatedly (`UQ(sym(.))`).

I am happy using `UQ` rather than `!!`, just because I'm more comfortable with traditional function notation.

Based on the comments, I got rid of the `namespace::function` notation and now my function doesn't look so verbose:

```
get_test_median = function(df, test_name) {

  stat_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_stat')
  df_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_df')
  median_col_name <- paste0(test_name, '_median')

  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(UQ(sym(df_col_name))) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(UQ(median_col_name) := median(x = UQ(sym(stat_col_name)), na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: I’m a **really big** ([!!!](https://github.com/klmr/modules)) fan of explicitly qualifying identifier names with a namespace. But even I think that in this case it would be better to attach `rlang` to make the code more readable. The package name (“rlang”) is a hint that these are things that should ideally be part of the core language. You wouldn’t use `base::for`, right?

Comment: I should have stated in my question that this is part of a package.  Given that it's part of a package, I believe I have to use the package::function notation.  Happy to be corrected on that if I've misunderstood the situation.

Comment: Even in the package, you can save the package::function notation if you make the corresponding imports in your namespace file, see http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports

Comment: It would be great if someone could answer "yes" or "no", given my edits in response to these comments.

Comment: I guess the question boils down to whether you are comfortable deducing the names of the columns from string, e.g. `get_test_median(test_name = 'test1')`. Column names can have strange edge cases, so if you are comfortable that you can always easily locate columns belonging to the specified model, everything in your example looks good